# f.select generating extra field in the options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using select tag for creating a option box

for creating a option box i have written following code

```
= f.select :user_id_eq,
  [raw("<option value=''>All Open Projects</option><option value='#{current_user.id}' selected='selected'>My Open Projects</option><optgroup label='Open Projects by Creator'>")] + current_user.company.projects.includes(:user).find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT user_id").collect {|p| [ p.user.name, p.user_id ] },
  {}, :'data-remote' => true, class: 'searchSelect'
```

But This is creating an extra blank field in the html content

```
<option value=''>All Open Projects</option><option value='7' selected='selected'>My Open Projects</option><optgroup label='Open Projects by Creator'>"
<option value="">All Open Projects</option>
<option value="7" selected="selected">My Open Projects</option>
<optgroup label="Open Projects by Creator">
    <option value="2">Cas Elliott</option>
    <option value="6">Rakl</option>
    <option value="5">Jas</option></optgroup>
```

The first line is extra line which is being created.
Why this line is createed any ideas???
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `options_for_select` helper instead. You'll find the documentation over at [options_for_select documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)